# Increase Directory number found

Tags: php

Ok.. here is my full code perhaps that will be more clear..

```
<?php

$dir    = './modules';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$files2 = scandir($dir, 1);

$module1=$files2['0'];
$module2=$files2['1'];
?>

<div id="linkDiv">
 <a href="#" onclick="showDiv('1');return false; showDiv('1');return false"><?php echo "$module1"; ?></a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="showDiv('2');return false; showDiv('2');return false"><?php echo "$module2"; ?></a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="showDiv('3');return false; showDiv('3');return false"><?php echo "$module3"; ?></a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="showDiv('4');return false; showDiv('4');return false"><?php echo "$module4"; ?></a><br />

</div>
<p>

<?php
echo "*************************";
?>
<div id="divLinks2">
<?php include "user_elements.php"; ?></a><br />
</div>
<?php echo "*************************"; ?>
```

Like I said I have coded here what I want but I would like to automate this as I add files to the /modules directory. In other words I want it to repeat the lines incrementing the values.

```
$module1
```

Becomes

```
$module2
```

As

```
$files2['This number increases']
```

That's about as clear as I can get.

Comment: Why do you need separate variables for them? You already have the array, just use that.

Comment: If you really want to create variables dynamically, read the PHP documentation on _variable variables_. But I've personlly never seen a good justification for them, since you can always do the same thing using an associative array.

Comment: What I want is $module# is going to = the directory name and therefore create the link I need later. For example the 2 directories in /modules are Helpdesk and Active directory. If I use the code: I get $module1 = Helpdesk and $module2 = ActiveDirecotry. I want the links to be added when a new directory is added to /modules.

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments. Update your question and show what you're trying to do. But whatever it is, I'll bet it can be done using an array instead.

Comment: Why do you need `$module#` variables to add links?

Comment: @ClaudeGarlick [why can't you do something like this instead.](http://pastebin.com/DdwvtnT2)

Comment: @Prix!!!! That's EXACTALY what I wanted to do! Your awesome thanks!